# How to configure foreign key in Entity Framework without an inverse navigation property?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I am new to Entity Framework and I am trying to get a couple models to work. I'll use the entities from [this microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key) as an example, since it is the one I am following to guide myself up.

My entities (without the non-relevant properties) look something like this:

```cs
public class Blog
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
}

public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

But my database looks like this:

`Blogs` table

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | uniqueidentifier |

`Posts` table

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | uniqueidentifier |
| Title | nvarchar |
| Content | nvarchar |
| BlogId | uniqueidentifier |

Notice the foreign key `BlogId` in the `Posts` table. Also notice that it the property is not explicitly defined in the `Post` entity in code.

When I try to do an insert using EF I get the following error:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'MyNamespace.DatabaseContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BlogId', table 'Posts'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

It is trying to insert a `NULL` value to the `BlogId` column in the `Posts` table, but I want it to grab the id from the `Blog` object in which that `Post` object is defined. (Posts cannot exist outside a blog, so they should always be defined inside a `List<Posts>`)

What I have done is the following:

```cs
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext()
    {
    }

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasMany<Post>(b => b.Posts);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne<Blog>()
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.Id);
    }
}
```

Here is my question: how can make EF grab the id from the blog containing the post without adding a `BlogId` property to the `Post` model? Is it even possible or am I forced to adjust my model's properties?

Also, I am using EF with a database-first approach.

**Edit**: some more information on the code.

The API receives the id of the `Blog` and the post's properties to create a new post in that blog. After that a commands runs that

```cs
...
var blog = await context.Set<Blog>().FindAsync(
    keyValues: new object?[] { id }, cancellationToken);
blog.Posts.Add(new Post
{
    Title = title,
    Content = content
});
await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Can you show the code from which you receive that error? I.e. how are you instantiating the entities and inserting them?

Comment: There is some cqrs and unit of work/repository pattern behind, but I'll try to add the essential pieces to the question.

Comment: There is a edmx mapping file that maps the tables in the database to the c# classes.  The mapping doesn't match your save to database.  You need to refresh the mapping and/or create new tables/columns in the database.

Comment: How would your database know which blog belongs to which post, unless there is a FK?  There has to be a link between the 2 somewhere !

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using database first you can create the tables with foreign key
and type this command

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=localhost;Database=[DatabaseName];Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -force
```

and EF will generate models for you in Models folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).